# How to quit Chrome process from within app (on Mac OS X)

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I have a custom web app written in Angular that is launched from a bash script. The app provides a GUI for the user to enter some information. Once the user is done, I'd like the bash script to continue execution, however I am unable to kill the chrome process from within the app, I can only close the window (Mac OS X). Is there a way to kill the chrome process when the window is closed? A command line flag or some other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is using the chrome.windows API, by using the remove() function, which will terminate a window and all its tabs. More information can be found here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-remove

Another solution, you could try accessing the following url in Chrome, but keep in mind that its only for testing purposes: chrome://kill.

Comment: This method is only exposed to extensions.

Comment: Since this isn't an extension, the remove() function will not work. How can I access chrome://kill? Is there a command line flag needed? Linking to it doesn't seem to work by default.